# RequireJs with moment.js does not trigger `init`

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs

My requirejs config is declaring [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and I'd like to set the default locale when requiring the library. So, I've tried this :

```
require.config({
  enforceDefine: true,
  noGlobal: true,
  baseUrl: '/js',
  shim: {
    'moment': {
      init: function (moment) {
        console.log("*** Moment loaded!");
        return moment;
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'moment': 'lib/moment-with-locales.min'

  }
});
```

However, calling `require(['moment'], function (moment) { ... });` does not invoke the `init` function inside the `shim` configuration.

What am I not getting, here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment.js defines itself as an AMD module and RequireJS won't call `init`.

From the documentation of RequireJS:

> The `init` function will **not** be called for AMD modules. For example, you
>   cannot use a shim init function to call jQuery's `noConflict`. See
>   [Mapping Modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap) to use noConflict for an alternate approach to jQuery.

From the master source of Moment.js:

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L2796

Comment: Do you know how I can get around this? Meaning, how I can automatically call `moment.lang(...)` once the module was loaded (only when and if required)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help me much. My `requirejs` config is based on an already known, local, `locale` variable that already holds the current locale, which is used to configure both [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and [bootstrap3-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/); in order to solve `moment.js`'s problem, I'd need to export that variable which seems silly to me.

Comment: I hoped I wouldn't need to refactor :) Oh, well, it's trivial anyhow.. Thanks for your answer!